# How to update Packagist using Bitbucket Webhook

Tags: bitbucket, webhooks, packagist

Previously you could have your Packagist packages updated automatically when you push to your Bitbucket repository by simply adding the POST URL for your Packagist account to a Bitbucket POST service.

However, Bitbucket have recently disabled POST services and replaced them with Webhooks.

So how can I have my packagist packages automatically updated when I push to my Bitbucket repository now?

Comment: I agree that this is an issue. Packagist has outdated information (says to select the POST service), bitbucket says Webhooks should be used instead of POST service, however using the webhook results in 406 errors. This was notified by others as well see https://github.com/composer/packagist/issues/541. It seems that the bitbucket-packagist commit hook integration is broken at the very moment

Comment: I've found an issue on github that will probably solve the problem: https://github.com/composer/packagist/issues/546